# Adding an image after certain href with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add a pdf.png to the beginning of every link that ends with .pdf with the following code:

```
$("a[href$=.pdf]").prepend('img src=/PATH/TO/THE/IMAGE/pdf.png');
```

but it's not doing the trick.

When I debug it with:

```
$("a[href$=.pdf]").click(function(){
    alert("I am an alert box");
    $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

it doesn't event pop the alert box out. I've taken a look at other questions in stackoverflow and it should work but aparently it doesn't. Could anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are  missing out the `single quotes`. Please read more about it over here. [endswith selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/).
And also you need to `wrap` the `tag` name inside a pair of `angular brackets (ex: <div/>)` while your are `creating a new element`, Your code does not contains that part too.

Try this,

```
$("a[href$='.pdf']").prepend('<img src="/PATH/TO/THE/IMAGE/pdf.png"/>');
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MC7Et/)

Comment: Very good, now it's popping the alert box when I debug it but it's still not prepending the image! Could you help me on that too?

Comment: @Ali You are missing out the angle brackets.! see my update now.

Comment: @undefined Is there anything ill, if we don't follow that self closing constraints.? Its a big doubt for me.?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: Not when you're passing the string into jQuery like that, no. And not when you're writing an HTML page. You only need or want that final slash if you're using XHTML. It's *tolerated* in HTML, but has no effect whatsoever.

Comment: W3C [states](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/syntax.html#syntax-end-tags) that [Void elements](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/syntax.html#void-element) should not have end tags. When the end tag is used for such elements browsers ignore it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  `but has no effect whatsoever` Thanks for your points.